# How to include multiple Css Class in ActionLink?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have two Css class like below:

```
     .btn
     {
          border:1px solid yellow;
     }

     .btn-info
     {
          background-color: blue;
     }
```

and an `ActionLink`:

```
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "btn btn-info" })</li>
```

As you can see I included those css class in `ActionLink` classes but it takes only first one. How should I add second one to `ActionLink` Css classes.

**Generated Html:**

```
     <a class="btn btn-info" href="/"></a>
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using. I tested this with MVC4 and it works just fine.

Comment: I tried this: @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "one one-two" }) and inspecting the anchor element shows me both classes applied.

Comment: I tried this too,those classes applied but It doesn't show second one styles.I thought something went wrong with my browser then tested in other such as chrome opera IE,but in the end nothing.I can't see the second one styles applied to my anchor.

Comment: Your styles are colliding in some way then. Check that they are not defined for a particular media query only, or that they are overridden with an inline style.

Comment: How it's possible when it's working with Html tags like `<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Click This"/>`.

Comment: Your classes are both being applied according to the generated HTML, you just have a CSS issue with something not working like you expected. Try looking in Chrome inspect element or IE Dev tools to see what the computed styles are and where they're coming from to see what you're missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })</li>
```

The fourth parameter is for the `routeValues` and the fifth parameter is for `htmlAttributes`.

Comment: isn't this the same as OP?

Comment: @DaveA No, I see null parameter value here

Comment: @DaveA, not at all, notice I have five parameters.

Comment: @SaberAmani, look at the generated HTML - this is the correct overload.

Comment: It's same as what I Post with different overloading.

Comment: @SaberAmani, there is no `string, string, string, object` overload.

Comment: Oh sorry yes, you are right. but It is not working.It still takes first one.

Comment: @Saber, so it rendered the HTML properly. It rendered with both classes. If the background color isn't taking that means there is another CSS style overriding the background color. This could occur if there was one on the element type itself, or if there was a definition on the element or class in a style sheet that was loaded **after** the one you're talking about in your question. But the HTML is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Michael is valid.

I suggest that you

Check the documentation [LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Browse the source code: [LinkExtensions](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1fa5fe9ce17f#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/LinkExtensions.cs)

It's really great to learn from it.